# Accessing route params within an adapter with ember

Tags: ember.js

I'm having issues accessing the current route params within an adapter.  I've tried looking in the store and type objects that are passed in but have not been able to find anything.

I know I could use window.href.location to access the string of the url and do some manipulation to access the route param, however I'm not comfortable hardcoding that in because the url may change.

Comment: What is your use case, why do you need route params in an adapter? Why can you not use them in a route/controller?

Comment: I need one of the route params to create my request url @Pavol

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use query argument passed to a method you use to query your data.

Look at the default implementation of rest-adapter's `queryRecord()`:

```
    query(store, type, query) {
      var url = this.buildURL(type.modelName, null, null, 'query', query);

      if (this.sortQueryParams) {
        query = this.sortQueryParams(query);
      }

      return this.ajax(url, 'GET', { data: query });
    },
```

It has access to the query argument and uses buildURL, you can override function `buildURL()` or `query()` and adjust it the way you need.

What you need to do afterwards is to use your route or controller to read query parameters from the url and pass to the store your query object to reflect your need.

Here is the link to [Ember-Data DS.Adapter API](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#method_query)

Comment: I'm getting the records using this.store.findAll which does not support the query parameter

Comment: I've tried referencing my model and using model.get('doc_fragment') however my ajax calls are not going out and it seems like my adapter is not being called at all.

Comment: What is `doc_fragment` in case of your model? An attribute to be loaded asynchronously? Why is it related to your primary question, I do not see the relation then.
You are right, `findAll()` supports no query params by now. I remember same issue and solved it by switching to calling `query()` from controller but delegating to `find()` in adapter, although it's a dirty solution.